# Security Question: Safety of storing key as a string

Tags: c#, .net, binary, hex

I'm using .NET 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition) and I've been storing sensitive key/license data as a string within the program. Suppose we have the following string:

```
string password = "admin123"
```

How safe is this from extraction within a hex editor or similar methods? I'm not well versed in hex editing, but after a few trivial searches it seems the string is obfuscated in some way.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Absolutely trivial - open your assembly up in any freely-available disassembler and all of your code will be there (with only minor differences to the original), including that string. .NET code by its very nature is very hard to obfuscate, and very easy to de-obfuscate.

Comment: Just compile your app/dll, then open it up in IL Spy (or tool of choice) and you'll see that you can easily navigate to this line and find the exact string. Anyone who has your program has your password. No hex editor needed.

Comment: You don't even need a disassembler software, ProcessExplorer (an improved Task Manager) can show strings from runing processes, including that kind of string.

Comment: Even if the password is not compiled, having it in memory would be enough to extract the password using [clr MD](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe whatsoever. Anyone with a disassembler (such as [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)) and your app can access your password.

To illustrate, I created a stupidly pointless and simple console app:

```
using System;
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string password = "admin123";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write($"My ultra top secret password is: {password}.");
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it, and opened it up in ILSpy. Here is what I saw:
[image: ILSpy screenshot of password in app]
Oh boy, that's no good...

In short, don't store sensitive info in plain text within your code. Assume nothing you code into an app/DLL is automatically obfuscated/safe. It is not safe. There are plenty of other posts on here that go into much better detail on that topic than I could, so I won't discuss the "how" here.